# How to write a method that takes a parameter with a covariant or contravariant bound in scala?

Tags: scala, traits, generic-variance

I am writing a scala program, which at some point should provide some status update for some task, and it could provide it also for groups of tasks. The point is that in different `phase`s, the details are different. So there are in fact various implementations for the `Details` trait, which I did not include here.

```
case class GroupMessage [+S <: Details]
(
  id: String,
  statuses: List[StatusMessage[S]]
) 

case class StatusMessage [+S <: Details]
(
  id: String,
  phase: Phase,
  statusDetails: S
)

sealed trait Details {
  def getDetails: List[String]
}
```

Now, the problem is the method that receives this status updates, and I cannot get its signature right. If I just put `def receiveStatus(status: StatusMessage)` the compiler complains that `StatusMessage` takes type parameters. I thought I need something like `def receiveStatus[S :> Details](status: StatusMessage[S])` but this does not compile either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The symbol `:>` doesn't exist - you probably meant to use `>:`.

But that still wouldn't compile, because you want `S` to be a subtype of `Details` (e.g. `SpecialDetails`, not a supertype (e.g. `Any`).

```
def receiveStatus[S <: Details](status: StatusMessage[S])
```

Comment: That's right. I am sorry to have asked such a stupid question! Maybe I can blame it on the notation not being intuitive and so easy to forget...

Comment: @Mahdi I have fallen for the same trap before :)

Comment: @Mahdi - I've done that before too. Just try to remember that the colon is always the last character before the type name.